# Error when trying to make a makefile in c++

Tags: c++, makefile

I have 3 files: Triliza.h, Triliza.cpp and Game.cpp.
This is my makefile

```
CC = g++
prog: Game.o
    $(CC) Game.o -Wall -Werror -pedantic -o Triliza
Game.o: Game.cpp Triliza.h
    $(CC) -Wall -Werror -pedantic -c Game.cpp
Triliza.o: Triliza.cpp Triliza.h
    $(CC) -Wall -Werror -pedantic -c Triliza.cpp
```

This is my main file: Game.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "Triliza.h"

Triliza *triliza;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
while (1)
{
    triliza = new Triliza();
    triliza->verifyFirstPlayer();
    triliza->loop();

    if (!triliza->playAgain())
        break;
}

return 0;
}
```

There is a error output:

```
g++ Game.o -Wall -Werror -pedantic -o Triliza
Undefined symbols:
"Triliza::Triliza()", referenced from:
  _main in Game.o
"Triliza::verifyFirstPlayer()", referenced from:
  _main in Game.o
"Triliza::loop()", referenced from:
  _main in Game.o
"Triliza::playAgain()", referenced from:
  _main in Game.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [prog] Error 1
```

So I suppose there are something wrong when I try to import each file together. Could anyone point me a correct way. Thanks

Edit: after changing there is another error came out.

```
make: *** No rule to make target `Trizilla.o', needed by `prog'.  Stop.
```

Thanks for all replies. I got it. because there is misspelling in Triliza

Comment: I mispelled it in my answer, its Triliza, not Trizilla.

Comment: You realize that you need to study `make`, right? Because you have multiple fallacies in your make file. First `CC` is indeed meant for the C compiler, not the C++ compiler, by convention. Second, your command (`... -o Triliza`) and your target name (`prog`) don't agree. And last but not least your makefile is redundant as it makes no use of built-in rules. See my answer for how it could be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not linking in Triliza.o when the executable is built due to a dependency issue. Change the prog target as follows:

```
prog: Game.o Triliza.o
    $(CC) Game.o Triliza.o -Wall -Werror -pedantic -o Triliza
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, but there is another error came out. "make: *** No rule to make target `Trizilla.o', needed by `prog'.  Stop."

Comment: @Harry, I mispelled it, sorry. Corrected

Answer (score 3):

Actually your make file could be as simple as this (only those two lines each):

```
CXXFLAGS:=-Wall -Werror -pedantic
prog: Game.cpp Triliza.cpp
```

although you probably wanted this instead:

```
CXXFLAGS:=-Wall -Werror -pedantic
Triliza: Game.cpp Triliza.cpp
```

although in both cases it won't explicitly take the (changed) header file into account.

`CXX` is going to be taken automatically to compile `.cpp` files using the built-in rules of GNU make. Do the following to see built-in rules and targets:

```
make -np -f /dev/null
```

(lowercase `-f` did have uppercase here before edit)

---

Now let's assume the dependencies for the header file(s) are relevant, too. In this case I'd adjust my second example to form the following (complete) make file:

```
CXXFLAGS:=-Wall -Werror -pedantic
Triliza: Game.cpp Triliza.cpp
dependencies: Game.cpp Triliza.cpp
    $(CXX) -M $(CXXFLAGS) $^ > $@

include dependencies
```

Only works if `$(CXX)` understands `-M`, obviously. GCC does (no matter whether invoked as `gcc` or `g++`).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `prog` does not depend on `Triliza.o`. Neither does `Game.o`

```
prog: Game.o Triliza.o
    $(CC) -Wall -Werror -pedantic -o Triliza $^
```

This should do it.
`$^` epxands the dependencies into a space delimited list.